# Why does the way in which I reference to another class change the behaviour of .Value controls?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, class, reference

In my code I use two classes. One contains the UI form, the other contains
a method to write to a file. During coding I found out some behaviour
which I don't understand. The code below shows (what I believe to be)
the relevant part. The file writing part is substituted by a `MsgBox` for simplicity.

I have the following controls in one form:

`NumericUpDown`
`Button`

With the following classes and methods:

```
Public Class One
    Private Sub Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button.Click
        Dim t As New Two
        t.Show()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Two
    Public Sub Show()
        Dim o As New One
        MsgBox(o.NumericUpDown.Value)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now when I click the `Button` the default `NumericUpDown.Value` shows.
When I adjust this value and click the button again, the old default value
keeps showing.

In the following code I removed the part `Dim o as New One` and I just use `One`
to reference to the other class. So:

```
Public Class Two
    Public Sub Show()
        MsgBox(One.NumericUpDown.Value)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now everything works as it should be. I click the `Button`, the default 
`NumericUpDown.Value` shows. I adjust the value, click the `Button`, the adjusted
value shows.

How is assigning `Dim o as New One` changing this behaviour?

This is my first week of coding with vb.net, so I might be doing things that don't make sense, but work for me. The only reason I put `Dim o as New One` in my actual code is that then I did not have to type "One" every time I referenced to the class,  but just had to type "o". Apparently this is not the way to go, but I am curious to know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this code instead:

```
Public Class One
    Private Sub Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button.Click
        Dim t As New Two
        t.Show(Me)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Two
    Public Sub Show(ByVal o As One)
        MsgBox(o.NumericUpDown.Value)
    End Sub
End Class
```

When you call `Dim o as New One` you are creating a new instance of the form so it won't show the values of the current form instance.